# Need help to convert the following R code to Python

Tags: python, r

I need help in converting the following R code in Python. Particularly with the matrix function from R (variable W), I find it difficult to convert it to Python as my only idea would be to use np.random.uniform() but don't know whether that works. Can anyone help me? Thanks!!

```
set.seed(1)

n = 100;
p = 400;

Z= runif(n)-1/2;
W = matrix(runif(n*p)-1/2, n, p);

beta = 1/seq(1:p)^2;   # approximately sparse beta
#beta = rnorm(p)*.2    # dense beta
gX = exp(4*Z)+ W%*%beta;  # leading term nonlinear
X = cbind(Z, Z^2, Z^3, W );  # polynomials in Zs will be approximating exp(4*Z)


Y = gX + rnorm(n);    #generate Y


plot(gX,Y, xlab="g(X)", ylab="Y")    #plot V vs g(X)

print( c("theoretical R2:", var(gX)/var(Y)))

var(gX)/var(Y); #theoretical R-square in the simulation example
```

Comment: If you don't know whether `np.random.uniform` would work, what happens when you try it?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

n,p = 100,400

Z,W = np.random.rand(n)-1/2, np.random.rand(n,p)-1/2

beta =np.ones(p)/np.arange(1,1+p)**2
gX = np.exp(4*Z) + np.matmul(W,beta)
Y = gX + np.random.rand(n)

plt.scatter(gX,Y); plt.xlabel("g(X)"); plt.ylabel("Y");

gX.var()/Y.var()
```